# Have to distinguish branches and tags in jenkins job

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

Suppose i have git repo with branches. I want to build any new tag in any branch, but i want to distinguish if master branch was tagged or another one.

When i start build, for instance, using refs/tags/1.4.2.5-lh, but tag 1.4.2.5-lh was in develop-new-feature branch.
${GIT_BRANCH} in this case equal refs/tags/1.4.2.5-lh without info about master or develop branch.

I've specified RefSpec as:

```
+refs/tags/*:refs/remotes/origin/tags/*
```

and Branch Specifier as

```
*refs/tags/${tag}*
```

Is it possible to detect it anyhow? Any other correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tags in Git do not belong to any branch. And they do not "tag" any branch. Tags are just pointers to a specific commits. A commit does not know which branches it belongs to.

So, it's not possible to say which branch tag was applied to. It's just incorrect.